# How to clone symfony and vue project to local machine?

Tags: symfony, vue.js

I am starting to work with a symfony-vue project and I need to clone it form github repository. Vue js is not in the assets folder but outside in a client side folder. So, I would like to ask do I have firstly to install symfony and vue js in my local machine (working with wampp) and then clone the project from a repository or just to clone a repository into an empty folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Symfony, usually it's enough to just clone git folder and run `composer install` command in the directory. This depends on presumption, that the project you want to clone is shipping `composer.json` (sometimes with `composer.lock`) files. I don't see a reason why Symfony based project wouldn't have one.

https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#installing-dependencies

For VUE.js and other JavaScript libraries it's either `npm install` or `yarn install` based on your preferred manager. Again, depending if you have `package.json` included.

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install.html

For more info about dependencies management in PHP and JavaScript realms you should study Composer, NPM documentation and usually also the documentation of the libraries and frameworks you want to use (Symfony, VUE).